# Mod_Auth_MySQL will not compile under Slackware 13

Tags: compiling, mysql, apache-httpd

I tried to add the auth_mod_auth (3.0.0) module to my Slackware 13 (apache 2.2 & MySQL 5.0) system.

I ran the usual command line for apxs (as mention in the BUILD file)

```
apxs -c -L/usr/lib/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -lm -lz mod_auth_mysql.c
```

but I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/apr-1.3.12/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile i486-slackware-linux-gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/mysql  -c -o mod_auth_mysql.lo mod_auth_mysql.c && touch mod_auth_mysql.slo
mod_auth_mysql.c:591: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:591: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:591: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[0].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:595: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:595: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:595: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[1].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:599: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:599: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:599: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[2].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:603: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:603: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:603: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[3].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:607: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:607: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:607: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[4].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:611: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:611: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:611: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[5].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:615: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:615: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:615: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[6].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:619: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:619: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:619: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[7].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:623: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:623: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:623: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[8].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:627: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:627: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:627: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[9].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:631: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:631: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:631: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[10].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:635: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:635: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:635: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[11].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:639: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:639: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:639: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[12].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:643: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:643: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:643: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[13].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:651: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:651: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:651: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[14].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:655: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:655: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:655: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[15].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:659: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:659: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:659: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[16].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:663: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:663: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:663: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[17].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:667: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:667: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:667: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[18].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c:671: error: expected expression before 'mysql_auth_config_rec'
mod_auth_mysql.c:671: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_auth_mysql.c:671: error: (near initialization for 'mysql_auth_cmds[19].cmd_data')
mod_auth_mysql.c: In function 'format_request':
mod_auth_mysql.c:947: warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Seems like the mysql library do not match what the code expect. I looked around and it seems to be the last available version of the module although is getting old (june 2005).

Has anyone made it work with a similar setup? 
I've been tweaking around for half a day without any success :-(

Comment: At a quick glance this kind of error could be triggered by a missing dependency (did you check that you had all the required stuff installed?), an out-of-date dependency (hopefully not the case if that's indeed the latest available module) or a misconfiguration (I've never compiled an Apache module, is there anything like `./configure`?). Is that your whole compilation log, or did you cut earlier output? The whole transcript of your session from when you unpacked might help.

Comment: Gilles, compiling a apache module is not the traditional "configure, make & make install". All go thru apxs command line who call gcc and the libtool. The whole output of the command is show up there! I have done this before but it was with apache 1.x and MySQL 3.x (long time ago!). I pretty sure that it have something to do with MySQL 5.0 because the doc from source forge speak about 4.1 and in 2005, MySQL 5.0 was not really around.

Comment: Someone report the exact same problem http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200512.mbox/%3C00c201c60502$1105e3f0$0200a8c0@ha30885127fb74%3E but no answer there!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here: http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=192391

And it works! :-)

It changes `APR_XtOffsetOf` to `APR_OFFSETOF` in the `.c` file.

Patch which solves the problem:

```
--- mod_auth_mysql.c.orig       2007-09-13 09:36:14.000000000 +0200
+++ mod_auth_mysql.c    2007-09-13 09:41:49.000000000 +0200
@@ -589,87 +589,87 @@
 static
 command_rec mysql_auth_cmds[] = {
        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLHost", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlhost),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlhost),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql server host name"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLPort", ap_set_int_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlport),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlport),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql server port number"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLSocket", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlsocket),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlsocket),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql server socket path"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLUser", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqluser),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqluser),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql server user name"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLPassword", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpasswd),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpasswd),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql server user password"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLDB", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlDB),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlDB),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql database name"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLUserTable", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpwtable),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpwtable),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql user table name"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLGroupTable", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlgrptable),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlgrptable),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql group table name"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLNameField", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNameField),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNameField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql User ID field name within User table"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLGroupField", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupField),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql Group field name within table"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLGroupUserNameField", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec,
mysqlGroupUserNameField),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupUserNameField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql User ID field name within Group table"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLPasswordField", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlPasswordField),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlPasswordField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql Password field name within table"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLPwEncryption", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEncryptionField),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEncryptionField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql password encryption method"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLSaltField", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void*) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlSaltField),
+       (void*) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlSaltField),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql salfe field name within table"),

 /*     AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthMySQLKeepAlive", ap_set_flag_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlKeepAlive),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlKeepAlive),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql connection kept open across requests if On"),
 */
        AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthMySQLAuthoritative", ap_set_flag_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlAuthoritative),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlAuthoritative),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql lookup is authoritative if On"),

        AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthMySQLNoPasswd", ap_set_flag_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNoPasswd),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNoPasswd),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "If On, only check if user exists; ignore password"),

        AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthMySQLEnable", ap_set_flag_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEnable),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEnable),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "enable mysql authorization"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLUserCondition", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlUserCondition),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlUserCondition),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "condition to add to user where-clause"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLGroupCondition", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupCondition),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupCondition),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "condition to add to group where-clause"),

        AP_INIT_TAKE1("AuthMySQLCharacterSet", ap_set_string_slot,
-       (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlCharacterSet),
+       (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlCharacterSet),
        OR_AUTHCFG, "mysql character set to be used"),

   { NULL }
```

Comment: Addendum : Modify also this line #define STRCAT ap_pstrcat
for #define STRCAT apr_pstrcat, otherwise your module will not load (looking for a missing ap_pstrcat symbol, the 1.3 API version instead of the 2.0 version)

Comment: Addendum 2 : If you compiled, installed and start your apache server and it still doesn't work then try this line in your *.conf ou .htaccess file :  AuthBasicAuthoritative Off. Since Apache 2.2 all the auth stuff changed a lot!!!